# How to Style an Image Which Is Set In the 'content' Property of A Pseudo Element Selector by 'url' Function

Tags: html, css

I have an icon which is an image:

```
<a href="some-path">
  ::before element
  "Text"
</a>
```

I have brought this to my document with `::before` selector:

```
.parent::before {
  content: url('image-direction');
  font-size: inherit; /* pay attention to this line */
  position: relative;
  top: some number (in pixels);
  left: some number (in pixels);
}
```

What I want to achieve is the image size to change based on the font size. Remember, when we changed the font size, the picture size used to change to.

What we see is that ONLY the height of the element is being changed while the width is staying unchanged, resulting the picture size to not change either.

I even tried this approach below:

```
.parent::before {
  content: url('image-direction');
  display: inline-block; /* in order for the element to respect width and height properties */
  width: some number (in em); /* in em, in order for it to change based on the text next to it */
  height: some number (in em);
  position: relative;
  top: some number (in pixels);
  left: some number (in pixels);
}
```

Now both width and height properties are changing correctly; but still nothing about the image. It's staying the same size.

How can I style an image which is set by the 'url' function of css in the content property?
How I can make the picture change its size, with any solutions?